# Calling number with iPhone on External Signal

Tags: ios, iphone, windows, bluetooth, synchronization

What I am trying to accomplish is to make ios app that listens to signal (not yet defined in which form) and then call the number specified in received message. I've found that is impossible when app is in background due to Apple privacy policy, but I want it to be possible only when in foreground.

I am wondering if it is possible to develop similar mechanism like when you connect iPhone to MAC so you can call using your MAC. But I want to use this funcionality from Windows too.

For example. Lets say that I have Windows app written in Java that stores contacts. I click call and the number is send to iPhone (like I said using not specified yet method) and then iPhone calls that number.

Is there any possibility to accomplish this. If yes, what the best way to send and receive message with number (for example bluetooth ).

Comment: What you describe is already standaard in iOS and MacOS fi you used the same Apple ID on both machines. 
But if you want to build this yourself you will have to look into bonjour.

Comment: You can have your app open a "tel:" URL, but the user will be prompted on the phone to confirm that they want to call the number.